# How to add data from mysql table to my already formatted html page

Tags: php, html, mysql

So basically I'm trying to make this news site that takes data from mysql table and put that inside my html formatting that I already made. Is there a way I can pull values and put them into my html tags. I have an entire html layout designed and I would like to just populate

```
<p><span class="date">April 24, 2017</span>
<h2><a href="#">Sed magna<br />ipsum faucibus</a></h2>
</header>
<a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<p>Donec eget ex magna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque venenatis dolor imperdiet dolor mattis sagittis magna etiam.</p>
<ul class="actions special">
<li><a href="#" class="button">Full Story</a></li></p>`
```

So I basically have html like this that is formatted nicely with placeholder words right now and I would like to instead fill them dynamically with the information from my tables inside my mysql server as soon as the user loads the page. Is there any way I can go about this. I've looked online a little and haven't found an answer so mabye I'm just not asking the right questions but I'd really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems straight forward, am I missing something?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //THIS SHOULD ECHO THE HTML TO THE PAGE BEFORE IT IS RETURNED TO THE CLIENT
        echo $row['html'];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Then again, I'm not sure this is the best architecture or will scale the best if the content is dynamic.